Creating the feeling of the character coming out of the flat monitor
I am working on a project that is going to be played in a concert, and we have a big monitor, but this monitor is flat, and I want this robot animation that I made to give the feeling of coming out of the monitor at the last moment. If you can help me, let me know


You should "waste" some screen space and use a low focal lenght, in order to enhance the illusion.
The wasted screen space should be black or - even better - with the same texture of the real surroundings of the physical screen.
Don't ever let some part of the head get over the border of the screen, because you would break the illusion.

